# liquibase-3.4.2 ClassNotFoundException: xml

Tags: liquibase

Java_home: jdk1.8.0_40

While running liquibase-3.4.2 (liquibase.bat) from the command line, I am getting:

```
INFO 1/31/16 3:52 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Unexpected error running Liquibase: xml

SEVERE 1/31/16 3:52 PM: liquibase: xml
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: xml
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:27)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:227)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1096)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:180)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:99)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: xml
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:279)
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:230)
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xml
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:277)
        ... 8 more
```

I have tried a lot of things over the past 3 hours, and am coming up with nothing.  Can anyone help?

Thanks :)

EDITED ...

This only happens when I try to use:

```
<includeAll path="changesets" resourceFilter="xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

in my changelog.xml ... changelog.xml validates fine, and the databaeChangeLog element is configured like so ...

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm donning my dunce cap now.

```
resourceFilter
```

is a supposed to be a class, not a string.

Apologies :)